# Decompiling ARM64 and understanding branch targets bounderies

Tags: objective-c, arm64, decompiling, mach-o

When decompiling code from arm64, how can one know if an unconditional branch instruction `b` is a branch to a label in the same function and not to some other function?

How do state of the art decompilers recognize if a branch target is still in the function or is it a new function? Do they rely on the branch target's value and see if it lands on a different section in the `TEXT` segment? 
What about branch targets that are in the same sections but are still considered new functions? Is there a rule of thumb for ARM64 saying that if a branch target is too far by some threshold from the current address it's considered a new boundary thus a new function? Like in x86 where you have different encodings for far jump and short jump, where short jump may be considered a label in a function and far jump probably not.

I might add that my target binaries I'm inspecting right now are Machos written in Objective-C, and I try to validate my findings using Ghidra, so it might be using some more heuristics like seeing if a jump target is in the `__stubs` section or the `__objc_stubs` section, or even analyzing block structures to identify more procedures (Although from Ghidra decompilation the last point seems like it doesn't identify these structures)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When decompiling code from arm64, how can one know if an unconditional branch instruction b is a branch to a label in the same function and not to some other function?

You can't really *know*. You can at best make an educated guess. In my experience, even state-of-the-art decompilers are quite bad at that. The good ones allow the user to manually override such detection.

The core problem is that there is no concept of a "function" at the assembly level. Labels that are exported to higher-level languages like C are expected to conform to a certain ABI, but for anything else, all bets are off. And even with exported things, if you're up against a malicious author (consider: malware), then they may choose to break this contract as well, in order to obscure how the binary works. But even with non-malicious binaries, if someone uses `-O3 -flto -moutline` that Apple supports for arm64 targets, you'll be in a world of hurt.

Some heuristics that you can use though:

- Has x30 been saved somewhere?
  Usually this will happen by an `stp x29, x30, [sp, ...]` instruction, and go along with decreasing `sp`. If this is the case, then with `b` you're likely looking at a branch within the same function. If this is not the case, then you don't know whether this is a tail call or a jump within the same function.

  Assumption: x30 is used as link register. An obfuscator could use something else, e.g. by means of `adr x17, ...; b _func` for the function call, and then `x17` would be the link register. This could also be randomised per-function.
- Are there any functions in between the current address and the jump target?
  Maybe your binary has symbols, maybe LC_FUNCTION_STARTS, maybe your decompilation has already identified function units, etc.

  Assumptions: functions have all their basic blocks next to each other, and aren't fragmented and spread out. Usually this is the case, but again, this assumption could be broken as part of an obfuscation technique.
- Is the jump target jumped to from any other function?
  If there are other callsites from code that you have already determined belongs to a different function, then the jump target can't belong to either of those functions.

  Caveat: function outlining, see the next point.
- Does the called code maintain the ABI in and out that you expect from a function?
  ABI violations should be trivial to determine. ABI conformance would need something like explicit register spilling to give you confidence. But if it conforms to the expected ABI, then it most likely is its own function. If not, then it's probably either part of the function that jumps to it, or it's code that was outlined.

But none of these are guaranteed to hit, and there will always be cases where both options remain possible.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So right now I'm using the symbol table, and prolouge analysis to find a set of entry points. I don't mind obfuscation techniques as the binaries I'm working on are system binaries and are not of malware nature.  After that I take all these entries and pass them to a branch analyzer to find more functions that we branch and link to (`bl`). So as for your second heuristic point, I feel I can do that check but unless I already know all the functions prior I can't tell if a data between the current address and the jump target is another function, it might be and it might

Comment: not unless I finish finding all functions it might give me false positives. Same for the third point, I feel as if I don't find all functions first I can't determine if more than 2 callsites call the same jump target. For example If I have a function `A` that we know for certain it's a function, and it has a branch to target `B` which might be a new function and might be not, and later we have another branch which gets us to *another* the same target 'B' can you say for certain that `B` is a function and not a label in the same function just because it has 2 callsites? I feel like we first

Comment: need to determine if the 2 callsites are different functions or just labels in our original function `A`, so for the first branch it's probably local branch in the function, but for the second branch, since it jumps to another location that then later branch to `B` it'll be hard to determine if this second jump prior jumping to `B` is a function by itself, counting towards 2 different callsites for `B`.
I feel like looking at the binaries I'm working on that most unconditional jumps that Ghidra identify their jump target as new functions, the jump target resides in some stub section

Comment: and so I wonder if this is a good assumption to make to check if a jump target is in different section or more specifically a stub section altogether?

Comment: Do you mean import stubs? In that case you can be sure it's a different function, but in any other case, all code is gonna be in the same section (usually `__TEXT.__text`). And yes, quite a bunch of heuristics require you to already have some information, but on the flip side, you will gain a lot of information as decompilation progresses - that is the whole point, after all. What this means is that decompilation should be an iterative process, because expecting to have all the information that you need beforehand is... very unrealistic, to put it mildly.

Comment: To provide an example of this that I commonly see in C++ code: member variables that can be re-initialised. Usually the code will check whether the pointer is null and if not, call some virtual destructor on it, then go on to allocate a new object and initialise it. The initialisation of the new object is what provides the required type information, but you won't get to that until you've skipped over the virtual destructor call. Once you have the type information, you can "go back" and populate the virtual destructor call with the necessary information that you didn't have before.